# Chef git resource always fails with "STDERR: fatal: Cannot force update the current branch"

Tags: git, chef-infra

As one of the steps in my Chef recipe, I need to checkout some code from github.  But every time I execute chef-client, it fails with the following output:

```
Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '128'
---- Begin output of git branch -f master 276d62661678d9249d7cafbc7dbbc50a94d212bc ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: fatal: Cannot force update the current branch.
---- End output of git branch -f master 276d62661678d9249d7cafbc7dbbc50a94d212bc ----
Ran git branch -f master 276d62661678d9249d7cafbc7dbbc50a94d212bc returned 128
[2016-02-18T00:46:11+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

I have tried changing the resource action from :sync to :checkout
I have also tried deleting the source folder before running the recipe.

recipe code:

```
git "/tmp/node_exporter" do
    repository 'https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter.git'
    checkout_branch 'master'
    action :sync
end
```

The repo does seem to get downloaded, so what's the deal?  Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Please include your recipe code too. I'm guessing you have checkout_branch set to master?

Comment: added the code.  Yeah, checkout_branch is set to master.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want that to read

```
git "/tmp/node_exporter" do
    repository 'https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter.git'
    revision 'master'
    action :sync
end
```

`checkout_branch` is a different thing and is a super-advanced feature you shouldn't need to touch often.